# How to make Doxygen show diamond inheritance graphs

Tags: c++, doxygen, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance, diamond-problem

Doxygen has a really neat feature whereby it will generate inheritance graphs from code. However, when using multiple inheritance from classes with a common base, the plot shows two separate base classes (even though I'm using virtual inheritance as signified by the dashed lines around the base class)

[image]

How can I make Doxygen plot something more like the following . . .

```
     D
    / \
   B   C
    \ /
     A
```

And not: (as happens without virtual inheritance)

```
     D
   /   \
   B   C
   |   |
   A   A
```

Comment: You know, I upvoted and favorited this a long time ago, but the more I think about it, the more I think that doxygen is actually right here, since D will have 2 instances of A.

Comment: There will not be 2 instances of A if the inheritance is virtual via `class B : public virtual A {}`

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04.3, using doxygen/doxywizard 1.8.13, I have the same problem with the "built-in class diagram generator". If I use `dot` (i.e. graphviz (dot) version 2.40.1) to generate the diagrams, then I get a proper diamond, but I lose the shading/dashed-outline signifying that the topmost class has been virtually inherited.
Very annoying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If you set the HAVE_DOT tag to YES then doxygen will assume the dot tool is
>   available from the path. This tool is part of Graphviz (see:
>   http://www.graphviz.org/), a graph visualization toolkit from AT&T and Lucent
>   Bell Labs. The other options in this section have no effect if this option is
>   set to NO
>   The default value is: NO.

Set to

> HAVE_DOT               = YES

Comment: Worth adding that if you don't have 'dot', on Ubuntu it's just a `sudo apt-get install graphviz` away.